# I am using eclipse and it stops responding when I open an android layout file

Tags: java, eclipse

After the program eventually closes it says: Java was started but returned exit code=-1073740791. After this it has a long list of specifications. I am running Windows vista. Any help appreciated

Comment: Have you allocated enough memory to eclipse at startup?

Comment: Which program?  Eclipse?  Something you wrote?  What's in this long list you mention?

Answer (score 0):

Start with -debug and check whether more stuff is logged or shown in the command console. It may give you more leads to the problem happening in background.